# add Music21 environment class in my project

Tags: python, pycharm, environment-variables, music21

I would be grateful if someone can explain me how should I add this environment to my project: http://web.mit.edu/music21/doc/moduleReference/moduleEnvironment.html#music21.environment.Environment

so far this is my code:

```
import os
import music21 as m21
from music21 import *

KERN_DATASET_PATH = "france"

def load_songs_in_kern(dataset_path):

    songs = []

    # go through all the files in dataset and load them with music21
    for path,subdir,files in os.walk(dataset_path):
        for file in files:
            if file[-3:] == "krn":
                song = m21.converter.parse(os.path.join(path, file))
                songs.append(song)

    return songs


def preprocess(dataset_path):
    pass

    # load the songs
    print("Loading songs...")
    songs = load_songs_in_kern(dataset_path)
    print(f"Loaded {len(songs)} songs.")




if __name__ == "__main__":
    songs = load_songs_in_kern(KERN_DATASET_PATH)
    print(f"Loaded {len(songs)} songs.")
    song = songs[0]
    song.show()
```

and I got this error which needs the environment set up:
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

but I do not realize from the documentation how to set this up in my project.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: Try running `python -m music21.configure` before trying to work with music21, but it seems like you're hitting a Python problem, not music21.  Try giving the full path from the `C:/` root to the directory, not just `france`

Comment: (I'm very happy to know that music21 is being used in Iran.  I wish you luck with any projects you do with in, and hope that I can someday give a talk about music21 there!)

Comment: @MichaelScottCuthbert actually I'm studying in France right now, but we have used your library in my bachelor program's Computational Intelligence course back in Iran and I assure your library has so many users in Iranian academic and they would be excited to have a talk with you:)

Comment: @BehnooshMzd -- let's make that happen. :-)